# Why am I getting "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0" error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, circular-list

Can someone please help me understand why I am getting this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at project1.Josephus(project1.java:25)
    at project1.main(project1.java:43)
```

---

```
public class project1 {
  public static int Josephus (int n, int k){
    ArrayList<Integer> circle = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int p=1; p<=n; p++) {                                                 
      circle.add(p);                                                      
    }
    System.out.println("There are " + n + " people in the circle.");

    ArrayList<Integer> kill_order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index=1; circle.size()!=1; index++){
      if (circle.size() > 1){
        index = (index + k - 1) % circle.size();
        System.out.println(kill_order.get(index) + " ");
        circle.remove(index);
      }
    }
    return circle.get(0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("You should sit in seat " + Josephus(6, 2) + " if you want to survive.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Because you never fill `kill_order`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are creating the ArrayList `kill_order`:
`ArrayList<Integer> kill_order = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

However, skipping a few lines unrelated to that list, you are already trying to read from it without never actually adding any data to that list:
`System.out.println(kill_order.get(index) + " ");`

This means you are trying to get an index, which cannot be found within the bounds, so an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown.

To avoid it, you need to add some entries to it as you did with the `circle` ArrayList before trying to read from it.